# Hadoop Security configuration related with hive and sqoop

Tags: hadoop

I'm using sqoop-1.4.6 to import data from MSSQL to hadoop-2.7.1

Using sqoop itself I can successfully list the table in MSSQL which mean it works fine. But when I tried  to import to hadoop, following error message raised:

```
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /tmp/libjars/opencsv-2.3.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1550)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3034)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:723)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1476)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1407)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:449)
```

So I check the log file of datanode, it gave the following infomation:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Failed to read expected encryption handshake from client. Perhaps the client is running an older version of Hadoop which does not support encryption.
```

Any idea how to change the configuration or how to deal with this problem?

Update:

It turns out that after I changed some configuration file, that problem begins. And the problem is not only about sqoop but hive has the same problem.

Configuration that I changed:
core-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>hadoop.rpc.protection</name>
<value>privacy</value>
</property>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>dfs.encrypt.data.transfer</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.encrypt.data.transfer.cipher.suites</name>
<value>AES/CTR/NoPadding</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.encrypt.data.transfer.cipher.key.bitlength</name>
<value>256</value>
</property>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try set dfs.block.access.token.enable to true.